# Unable to get mac address for tablets in android

Tags: android, mac-address

Right now i am trying to get mac address for tablets and smartphone in  android.

I have tried with the below code.

```
TelephonyManager tm =   (TelephonyManager)Current_activity_name.this.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); 
String str_macid = tm.getDeviceId();
```

this code is working only for smartphone but not for tablets.Why?

Suggestions please..

Thanks for your precious time!..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the MAC address of the WiFi modem you first need a permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Next

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
String macAddress = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getMacAddress();
```

This works if a WiFi connection currently exists.